# github-linguist does not recognize vendored files from .gitattributes

Tags: gitattributes, github-linguist

Github's linguist is detecting many files in my repos which are vendored, especially JavaScript. [I found out](https://github.com/github/linguist#vendored-code) that a `.gitattributes` can be used to configure linguist to ignore several files for statistics count.

But this doesn't work, in any way I try. It seems like it simply doesn't matter whats defined in my `.gitattributes`. So far, I've tried the following:

```
deploy/static/js/pdfjs/*    linguist-vendored
deploy/static/py/Brython-3.7.1/*    linguist-vendored

deploy/static/js/pdfjs/build/pdf.js linguist-vendored
deploy/static/js/pdfjs/web/debugger.js  linguist-vendored
deploy/static/js/pdfjs/web/viewer.js    linguist-vendored
deploy/static/py/Brython-3.7.1/brython.js   linguist-vendored

/deploy/static/js/pdfjs/*   linguist-vendored
/deploy/static/py/Brython-3.7.1/*   linguist-vendored

**/pdfjs/*  linguist-vendored
**/Brython-3.7.1/*  linguist-vendored
```

The result when I run `github-linguist --breakdown` is always

```
JavaScript:
deploy/static/js/app.js
deploy/static/js/pagination.js
deploy/static/js/pdfjs/build/pdf.js
deploy/static/js/pdfjs/web/debugger.js
deploy/static/js/pdfjs/web/viewer.js
deploy/static/py/Brython-3.7.1/brython.js
sources/gulpfile.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've run `git check-attr` now on file `deploy/static/py/Brython-3.7.1/brython.js` and it gives me

    $ git check-attr -a deploy/static/py/Brython-3.7.1/brython.js 
    deploy/static/py/Brython-3.7.1/brython.js: linguist-vendored: set

So the attributes seem to be set.

Comment: What's the repository's URL?